# Parse Postgres date stored as string including offset timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, timezone, timezone-offset

I have some dates stored as strings in a postgresdb

```
"Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700"
```

I want to treat those dates as dates.

I can use

```
to_timestamp(date,'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

But I can't work out how to deal with the timezone. there appears to be OF as the parameter for the offset.

If I use

```
to_timestamp(date, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS OF')
```

The query hangs. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong there.

Note: I'm using activerecord and rails. so the query is actually

```
Model.all.order("to_timestamp(date,'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH24:MI:SS OF') DESC")
```

Comment: Maybe? `Time.zone.parse("Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700").to_date`. just a guess. Check out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Comment: PostgreSQL is smart enough: `select timestamp with time zone 'Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700';` returns `2016-06-24 14:13:26+03` for my location.

Comment: @Abelisto Is there a way of doing that with the to_timestamp method? The issue is that I'm trying to do it with an order not with a select.

Comment: It was just an example. In you case it could be `Model.all.order("date::timestamptz DESC")`

Comment: @Abelisto Do you want to put that answer below. It's absolutely correct.
I searched high and low for how to do it. Really not clear from the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports several formats for date/time/timestamp values input. [See the reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT).

Your format is also supported so the simple type cast can be used. There are three ways and also two type notations in the PostgreSQL:

`timestamp with time zone` or shorter `timestamptz`

and type cast like:

```
cast('Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700' as timestamp with time zone)
timestamp with time zone 'Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700'
'Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700'::timestamptz
```

which is equal. You can use any combinations depending on your taste.

So answering to your question:

```
Model.all.order("date::timestamptz DESC")
```

should make the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

> "Fri, 24 Jun 2016 04:13:26 -0700".to_datetime

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but I can only do that once I've brought back the query. i.e. I was hoping for something that I could do purely with activerecord.

Comment: You mean to say, you need that date value in order by query?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can use field name in order by query not value of that field.